# Нет доверия сертификату Charles на Android (ненадёжный)

Tags: android, сертификат, fiddler

Появилась проблема подключения Android устройства к Charles, сертификат установлен, но отображается как ненадежный, из-за этого в Чарльзе не отображается трафик, все перепробовал, но результатов нет, на IOS все работает корректно (аналогичная ситуация и с программой Fiddler).

До этого всё прекрасно работало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]